# How can I build a Django query without knowing what fields I will query on?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm new to Django and kinda new to Python too, and I'm trying to build a query. I have some fields in a dictionary and I don't know which will be used in a query (they're coming in from a form.)

I've got something kinda working, but I can tell it's broke, and it's terrible, not reusable code:

```
if 'street_number' in params:
    query = query.filter(addresses__street_number=params['street_number'])
if 'street_name' in params:
    query = query.filter(addresses__street_name=params['street_name'])
if 'district' in params:
    query = query.filter(addresses__district=params['district'])
if 'city' in params:
    query = query.filter(addresses__city=params['city'])
if 'county' in params:
    query = query.filter(addresses__county=params['county'])
if 'state' in params:
    query = query.filter(addresses__state=params['state'])
if 'country' in params:
    query = query.filter(addresses__country=params['country'])
if 'zip_code' in params:
    query = query.filter(addresses__zip_code=params['zip_code'])
if 'precinct' in params:
    query = query.filter(addresses__precinct=params['precinct'])
```

I believe it's joining once for every time I call query.filter. When I view the SQL it generates I see this mess:

```
SELECT `voters`.`id`, `voters`.`created_at`, `voters`.`updated_at`, `voters`.`first_name`, `voters`.`middle_name`, `voters`.`last_name`, `voters`.`name_prefix`, `voters`.`name_suffix`, `voters`.`ethnicity`, `voters`.`gender`, `voters`.`i360_id`, `voters`.`rnc_id`, `voters`.`congressional_voter_id`, `voters`.`state_voter_id`, `voters`.`county_voter_id`
FROM `voters`
INNER JOIN `voters_addresses` ON (`voters`.`id` = `voters_addresses`.`voter_id`)
INNER JOIN `addresses` ON (`voters_addresses`.`address_id` = `addresses`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `voters_addresses` T4 ON (`voters`.`id` = T4.`voter_id`) 
INNER JOIN `addresses` T5 ON (T4.`address_id` = T5.`id`)
WHERE (`addresses`.`city` = Nashville AND T5.`state` = TN) LIMIT 10
```

(there's also a couple other things going on in the SQL, like joining on phones, but that's not related to this problem.)

Note the extra joining on voters_addresses and addresses. Can I refactor this so it uses one filter() call instead? Alternatively, can I build a query starting with each of the related models (Address, Phone, etc.) and combine them later, somehow? Something like

```
Voter.objects
  .whereExists(Address.objects.filter())
  .whereExists(Phone.objects.filter())...
```

?

Comment: Do you have your query backwards? it looks like you need to filter addresses then get the related object

Comment: Would changing the context to Address change how the filtering is built? I suspect I'd still have many filter function calls. Also I'm potentially querying on other tables as well (voters, phones, emails, etc.)

Comment: I believe it would because you're having to do a related lookup every time, im not sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built in way to do it by you can kinda optimise it.

```
def set_if_not_none(mapping, key, value):
    if value is not None:
        mapping[key] = value


def view(request):
    sort_params = {}
    get_params_needed = ['street_number', 'street_name', 'district'] # And list all of them you need.

    for param in get_params_needed:
        set_if_not_none(sort_params, 'addresses__' + param, request.GET.get(param))

    result = YourObject.objects.filter(**sort_params)

    ...

    return render(...)
```

The code is self explanatory. Hope it helps.

Comment: It's the `**` that does it, right? I'm new to Python but it looks like passing a dictionary into a function using the double-star operator will actually expand it into key=value arguments for the function. (In case anyone else didn't know.) Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Yeah the double asterisks is unpacking the dictionary if pass it to a function.